# RadioButton TextColor gone wrong? How to change it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, radio-button

I have a weird problem here.
so I decided to practice making Custom Radio Button like Pills, and then it did not work like what I coded.

I set the color with Black and White for the text, but my Radio button text turns Pink. Eyy yo, what is going on here?

[image]

Here's my code:

**My RadioGroup:**

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rumah"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_selector_null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/radio_selector_text"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:text="Apartemen"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_selector_null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/radio_selector_text"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:text="Kos"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_selector_null"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@drawable/radio_selector_text"/>
```

**radio_selector_null.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

**radio_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_pill_true" />
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_pill_false" />
</selector>
```

**radio_pill_true.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`
    <solid android:color="?colorPrimary" />  <-- Green
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

**radio_pill_false.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`
    <solid android:color="#F3F3F3" />  <-- White
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>
```

**radio_selector_text.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@color/black_28" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `radio_selector_text.xml` file should be present in `color/` res directory and not in `drawable/` directory
2. The colors in the file should defined using `android:color="@color/black_28"`

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help! i just change with the number 2. I appreciate it!